# Why do I need prevProps with prevState in componentDidUpdate()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a simple counter app:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAddOne = this.handleAddOne.bind(this);
    this.handleMinusOne = this.handleMinusOne.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      const stringCount = localStorage.getItem('count');
      const count = parseInt(stringCount);

      if (isNaN(count) === false) {
        this.setState(() => ({ count }));
      } 
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.count !== this.state.count) {
      localStorage.setItem('count', this.state.count);
      console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    }
  }

  handleAddOne() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count + 1
      }
    });
  }
  
  handleMinusOne() {
    console.log('handleMinusOne');
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count - 1
      }
    });
  }
  
  handleReset() {
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        count: 0
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleAddOne}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleMinusOne}>-1</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleReset}>reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The question I have is with `componentDidUpdate()`. In it, I am checking to see if the `prevState.count` is not the same as the `this.state.count`. If it is not the same, then I set `localStorage` to the new count. If it is same, I do nothing.

In the current componentDidUpdate(), I need `prevProps` as an argument for this function to work correctly. For example, if I just have this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    if (prevState.count !== this.state.count) {
      localStorage.setItem('count', this.state.count);
      console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    }
  }
```

Then the component sets `localStorage` every time the reset button is pressed repeatedly, even though the count remains at 0.

What is going on? Why do I need `prevProps` for `componentDidUpdate()` to work correctly, if I am never using `props` in that function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first parameter in `componentDidUpdate` is `prevProps`. The second parameter is `prevState`. [The documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) clearly states that:

> componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)

This

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {...}
```

is not a correct signature for the hook. Even though the first parameter was called `prevState`, it contains previous props.

It's possible to alternate function parameters based on its arity but this isn't implemented in React and considered a bad practice in general because this leads to more complex signatures.

To not cause linter warnings, unused parameters can be underscored by convention:

```
componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about underscore convention, already thought I'd need to do eslint-disable after all and I got away without it so far :)

Comment: @cincplug Yes, the convention surely can be backed by eslint, https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern .

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't matter if you are using `prevProps` in your function or not, it has to be included, since the arguments order in functions **does matter**.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)
```

If you'd omit the `prevProps` argument, the `prevState` (even tho the name would say clearly that it's previous version of state) it would stand for the previous version of props.

It's just a blank. You can use either an underscore, to tell others (or just yourself) that it's not used in that function.

```
componentDidUpdate(_, prevState)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `componentDidUpdate` receives `prevProps` as the first argument and `prevState` as second. If you write the function as `componentDidUpdate(prevState)` it is receiving `prevProps` but it will be named `prevState`. No matter how you name the arguments, they will be `prevProps`, `prevState`, and `snapshot`, respectively.

If you don't need the first argument, you can use an underscore eg. `componentDidUpdate(_, prevState)`.